# Convertion of date from yyyy-mm-dd(2013-01-01) to Month day, year(Jan 1, 2013) in android

Tags: android

I need to know how to convert a date from `yyyy-mm-dd` (e.g. `2013-01-01`) to Month day, year (eg `Jan 1, 2013`) in Android.

I want to convert the date from database(`2013-01-01`) in to a string like this `Jan 1, 2013`. 
and put it in a edit text in android..

Comment: What database are you using? You're likely better off converting in your query then assigning it to a string than trying to deal with it as a string. EDIT: NVM Didn't know about `SimpleDateFormat` class. Listen to them instead.

Comment: Are you using SQLite? If your are, you might want to look at this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get the date as a `String`, then you can use a `SimpleDateFormat` to convert it to a `Date`. Then use again a `SimpleDateFormat` to get the `Date` as a `String` in the format you need.

This should do what you require.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(yourDateAsString);
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
String yourFormatedDateString = sdf.format(date);
```